# Receiving the array throw Wso2Dss and Store into PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

My client sending the Data in array format like {1,2,3}

i am receiving in  array format throw Wso2 DSS and insert into the PostgreSql DataBase.

```
My WSo2 DSS Insert query is:-

<data name="SalArray">
   <config id="default">

   <query id="Insert" useConfig="default">
      <sql>insert into sal_emp(name,pay_by_quarter,schedule) values(?,?,?)</sql>
      <param name="name" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="pay_by_quarter" ordinal="2" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
      <param name="schedule" ordinal="3" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>

   <operation name="Insert">
      <call-query href="Insert">
         <with-param name="name" query-param="name"/>
         <with-param name="pay_by_quarter" query-param="pay_by_quarter"/>
         <with-param name="schedule" query-param="schedule"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

While i am inserting the data i am getting error

```
Error:-
Current Request Name: Insert
Current Params: {schedule={'abc'}, name=anil, pay_by_quarter={1,2,3}}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{1,2,3}"
```

Someone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Looking at your SQL query .. you have a simple insert. Therefore you do not need array type as an input type for  pay_by_quarter,schedule. Since, your SQL query only expect one value for pay_by_quarter and  schedule you don't need array support for your query. So this should work if you remove paramType="ARRAY" as SQL query it self is not needing an array.

If you want an example with ARRAY for SQL please refer this. You can only use this Array feature for SQL syntax like "in" where you can give multiple values

ie

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City IN ('Paris','London');

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City IN (:Cities);
```

Comment: Thank you Poohdedoo,But my requirement is receiving  array contains columns of{1,2000,20} means{id no,salary,age}, how can i split and insert in table  with respected columns.Please guide me..

Comment: If you can give me the correct SQL syntax for that (with your actual working values) I can give u a sample from data services side

Comment: Hi Poohdedoo, here is my query, can you give  me the data service side q for this  **INSERT INTO memployeecount (CompanyCode,NoofEmployees) VALUES
   ('SPS', 1000),
   ('SPS', 2000),
   ('SPS', 3000),
   ('SFS', 500),
   ('SFS', 600),
   ('SFS', 700);**

Comment: For these types of SQL queries its better to use DSS batch request feature where you can enable batch request at the DSS creation time and send insert values as a batch please refer http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS311/Batch+Processing+Sample for more details

Answer (score -1):

Seems the array is sent incorrectly. [Refer this documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS301/Data+Types#DataTypes-array) on how to properly send an array type in a soap message.

Comment: Thank you Rajeev,But my requirement is receiving array contains columns of{1,2000,20} means{id no,salary,age}, how can i split and insert in table with respected columns.Please guide me.